# Trying to use loop to find unique variables in a dataset and use sapply to apply a certain function

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I am trying to use a loop to find the unique variables in an `NHANES` dataset and use `sapply` to apply the function `nhanes_uniq` to the `NHANES` library. I keep getting an error, Here is the code:

```
library(NHANES)
nhanes_uniq <- vector("integer", ncol(NHANES))
names(nhanes_uniq) <- names(NHANES)
for (i in names(NHANES)) {
  nhanes_uniq[i] <- n_distinct(NHANES[[i]])
}
sapply(NHANES[,ind], nhanes_uniq)
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'nhanes_uniq' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Comment: what function is `nhanes_uniq`? You are defining it as a vector, not a function here.

Comment: `names(NHANES)[sapply(NHANES, is.factor)]` this ll get you the result you want

Comment: Oops, I see. I tried to create a loop but did not define a function. However, not sure what I can do from here...

Comment: Maybe something like that `apply(NHANES, 2, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))` instead of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Abdessabour, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might solve your problem

```r
names(NHANES)[sapply(NHANES, is.factor)]
```

`sapply(NHANES, is.factor)` to get a logical vector for of the columns that are factors. use it as a subset to get the names of the factor vars.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
NHANES %>%
    select(where(is.factor)) %>%
    names
```